# How should I go about recreating the water from this picture?

Tags: materials, shaders

[image: Island Blend]

I can't figure out the best way to recreate the water here. I wasn't sure if I should maybe simulate some fluid and instead of having a glossy material just usea diffuse or mix shader maybe? I know I could just color a plane instead of making actual waves.... but I just don't know the best way to approach this, help me out please :[]

Also, I would appreciate any feedback or pointers!

Thanks!

(Here is the reference)

[image: Island ref]

Comment: Since you seems to be taking an approach that has solid colours(no smooth transitions), Maybe add some fake wave shapes with different colours and just lay them on top of the water.

Comment: Could you please upload only reference picture? It's hard to see what's exactly going on there. It could be wave, it could be paint.

Comment: I uploaded the reference.

Comment: Also adding fake waves as objects is a pretty good idea. What about the shimmering effect?

Comment: Adding fake waves will give you different result from reference image because of lightning. To achieve the same effect I would personally go with Texture Paint (if you have Graphic Tablet). It will be easier and faster.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a graphic tablet :p and as far as drawing with mouse goes, forgetaboutit x()

Comment: I agree texture paint would be the best solution. for the shimmering effect you could also do that in texture paint mode or you could make a few white emission objects and make them hair particles on the water